# Looping through Input Items to get Min Max Value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question about JQuery Min Max Validation looping through dynamic created input items.
In my php page i have a dynamic table who loops through the data in the DB.
Sometimes i have an table with 3 input Items (Cells) sometimes with 6 or 12 input items.
With jquery i found to validate min - max value of data, but it works only for the first input item.
How can loop throug all the input item to get the same min max validation?

Here the JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").click(function(){

                var enteredValue = $("input:#value_one").val();
                var min=1;
                var max = 3;
                var num = parseInt(enteredValue);

                if (min > num || max < num) {
                    alert('Number ' + num + ' is not a number between ' + min + ' and ' + max);
                    return false;
                }
        });
    });
```

Here apart of the PHP HTML Code:

```
    foreach($datas as $idactivite=>$dat){
        $totalactiv=0;
        $nbdiviseur=0;
        foreach($dat as $dd){
            $totalactiv+=$dd["note"];
            $nbdiviseur++;
        }
        $mamoyactiv=$totalactiv/$nbdiviseur;
        $position=3;
        $mamoyactiv = substr($mamoyactiv, 0, $position);
        $moyenneverticale[$idactivite]=$mamoyactiv;

// Here the input Item who loops through the DB Query to get them values:       

        $htmldroit.="<td id='myguaNote' bgcolor='$bgcolor' align='center'>

        <input name='".$idactivite."_".$idagent."' id='value_one' maxlength='1' class='grand' value='".$dat[$idagent]["note"]."' ></td>";

        $totalfamille+=$dat[$idagent]["note"];
        $TabRes[$ind] += $dat[$idagent]["note"];
        $TabObj[$ind] = "&nbsp;";
        $TabResColor[$ind]=0;

        $ind++;
    }
```

Somebody any ideas?

THX in advance

Comment: Can you include the HTML output of the PHP script?

Comment: Instead of `$("input:#value_one")` did u mean `$("input#value_one")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not really selecting the input field which was actually clicked.

Replace `var enteredValue = $("input:#value_one").val()` with

```
 var enteredValue = $(this).val();
```

The callback function from `click` holds a reference to the clicked DOM element in the `this` keyword. wrap it in `$()` to make it a jQuery object and finally call `val()` on it.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bpa5d/)

*Edit:*
To validate multiple input fields on button click I used a helper class `validate`. Assuming all input fields you want to validate have this class you can bind some code to submit button's on click:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    $(".validate").each(validateField);
});
```

First all elements having the class `validate` will be selected and on this collection we call jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which takes a function handle as argument. This function (`validateField` in this case) should take to input arguments (index and element, see the documentation for more details - if you think of a strange for for a "for in"-loop you're not far off.).
I moved the your validation code in this function and simply replaced `$(this)` by `$(element)`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mg4xq/)

Comment: Hi Yoshi
it works fine, but only when i click in the input item. How that can work when i click the Validate Button? 

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpa5d/1/

THX

Comment: Yeah it works i get an alert on the submit of my validate Button, many thanks, but the page didn't stops when i confirm the alert with OK . It send it to my other page. Do you know why?

Comment: @achillix It's hard to tell without actually seeing the generated HTML. Maybe you have a `submit` hidden somewhere causing the browser to send the form? Or another click handler? If the problem persists consider opening another question for this problem :)

Comment: OK, i will try before to resolve the problem, if doesn't work, i will created a new Question. Thank you (and all the others here) for your help!!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

few tips

if you are working with dynamic data then don't use simple 'click' function, instead try [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ( with jQuery **1.7+**)

```
 $('document').on('click', 'input', function(){

   var enteredValue = $(this).val();
   //your rest of code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

||
    if (min > num || max < num) {

change to

```
// For a number not between min and max
if (num < min || num > max) {

// For a number between min and max
if (num >= min && num <= max) {
```

For testing:

```
        <script>

        function test(){

            $html = document.getElementById("msg");

            num = 100;
            min = 10;
            max = 100;

            if (num < min || num > max) {
            $html.innerHTML = "Num is not between min and max";
            return;
            }

            if (num >= min && num <= max) {
            $html.innerHTML = "Num is between min and max";
            return;
            }

        }

        </script>
        <body onload="test()">
        <div id="msg" style="border:1px solid #000000; height:100px">Answer has not been found!</div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Nope, assuming `min` < `max` how shall `(num < min && num > max)` ever evaluate to `true`? (no complex numbers! :3 )

Comment: still needs to reveresed yoshi. Its the && that needs to be || :3

Comment: Reversed in which way? WLOG consider `min`. Then `num` has to be less than `min` for failure. Writing `num < min` or `min > num` is semantic identical.

Comment: I really don't care yoshi... I updated a html test output to ensure it's correct above. It works... It's correct... I need no more...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which will keep things up-to-date as the page changes, whereas the click you have is just on the state of the page when it's created.  Try:

```
$("input").on("click",function(){
```

Comment: For the sake of clean code I support your suggestion. I think it's easier to `STRG+F` for `on` instead of `click`, `fade`, `touch`, `whatEverElse` but yeah, that's personal style :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

//========== Prototype to find out min value in an Array=========================

```
        Array.prototype.min = function() 
        {
            return Math.min.apply(null, this)
        }
```

//============= Jquery Scripting===================================================

```
            $selector=$("input");  //Your selector which is cursoring your inputs
            $aryVal=new Array;     //Define an Array
            $selector.each(function() //Iterate to all the input
            {
                $aryVal.push(this.value); //push the value to array
            });

            var min = Math.min.apply(null, $aryVal);  //Getting min value from array
            alert(min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice when creating a dynamic amount of elements which are being used to inject a variable somewhere is:

1. Give unique ID for identification.
2. Use CSS class. Class styles are meant to be repeated, ID's are not.

So if I were to generate a number of inputs 1 to 100

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
{
    $IdAndName = "input" . $i;
    echo("<input type='text' id='" . $IdAndName . "' name='" . $IdAndName . "' class='myStyle'/><br>\n");
}
```

Now you would have HTML elements with ID input1 to input100

You can then use the JQuery click event as you have, then use $(this).val() to retrieve it's value on click.